# Быстрое чтение данных

Tags: java, производительность

У нас есть следующая конструкция, которая отвечает за чтение:

`BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

Входные данные представляют собой список интовых значений разделенных пробелом. Т.е. N строк, в которых K значений.

Необходимо прочитать максимально быстро.

Пробовал читать следующим образом:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while((String line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    String[] strNums = line.trim().split("\\s+");
    for (String strNum1 : strNums) {
        if (strNum1.length() > 0) {
            data[counter] = Integer.parseInt(strNum1);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Данное решение показывает неудовлетворительную производительность. Подскажите пожалуйста, как прочитать входные данные быстрее?

Comment: А пробел между числами строго один? А значение в `System.in` это строки чисел, разделенных `\n`, т.е. находящихся на разных строках?

Comment: @gil9red да, все верно.

Comment: разделение на строки критично, или просто нужно считать N*K чисел?

Comment: @zRrr просто считать в массив

Comment: @МстиславПавлов http://acm.timus.ru/help.aspx?topic=java посмотрите пример со `StreamTokenizer`.

Comment: @zRrr Спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В плане быстродействия лучше использовать как можно меньше объектов.

Предложу так:

Прочитать файл как набор байт, я так понял, что файл спокойно помещается в память.

JDK 7:

```
byte[] all = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("файл"));
```

jdk младше (так возможно даже быстрее):

```
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("file");
    byte[] all = new byte[in.available()];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];
    int countReadAll = 0;
    while(in.available() > 0){
        int read = in.read(buffer);
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, all, countReadAll, read);
    }
    System.out.println(new String(all));
```

Такими трюками можно избежать постоянного создания `String`.

---

Дальше без `String` никуда. Поэтому приведем все к строке:

```
  String text = new String(all);
```

Дальше, я честно не знаю что быстрее, поэтому попробуйте сначала `Integer.parseInt()`, т.к. он возвращает int и скорее всего будет быстрее. Для получения отдельной цифры можно использовать предложенный `StringTokenizer`.

```
String delimiter = " " + System.lineSeparator(); //чтобы делить по пробелу и по переводу строки
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(x, delimiter);
int[] ch = new int[tokenizer.countTokens()];
int i = 0;
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    ch[i++] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение оказалось наиболее производительным.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [сканер](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Для считывания из консоли можно использовать `new Scanner(System.in)`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9";

        List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(input)) {
            while (s.hasNextInt()) {
                items.add(s.nextInt());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(items);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

Код ниже работает уже с `String`, но не думаю, что проблема из нужного потока (stdin, сеть или локальный файл) получить строку, тем более вопрос о другом.

*Код с регуляркой быстрее сканера примерно в 8 раз.*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9";
        //System.in
        List<Integer> items = null;
        int number = 10000;

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            items = useScanner(input);
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Elapsed time %s nanoseconds", (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / number));
//        System.out.println(String.format("Items: %s\n", items.size()));


        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            items = useRegExp(input);
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Elapsed time %s nanoseconds", (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / number));
//        System.out.println(String.format("Items: %s\n", items.size()));
    }

    static List<Integer> useScanner(String text) {
        List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(text)) {
            while (s.hasNextInt()) {
                items.add(s.nextInt());
            }
        }

        return items;
    }

    static List<Integer> useRegExp(String text) {
        List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String strNum1 : text.trim().split("\\s")) {
            items.add(Integer.parseInt(strNum1));
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

Консоль:

```
Elapsed time 57040 nanoseconds
Elapsed time 6758 nanoseconds
```

Comment: Читал, что сканер работает более медленно по сравнению с `BufferedReader`, но попробую, спасибо.

Comment: К сожалению данный способ показывает низкую производительность.

Comment: А какие объемы данных? А на сколько проигрывает BufferedReader?

Comment: Несколько мб текста состоящего из целочисленных значений разделенных пробелом. Сканнер тратит на чтение >500ms. Мне бы хотелось уложится в ~50ms(что для такого объема вполне нормально).

Comment: @МстиславПавлов Обновил ответ, добавил пример с регуляркой и с замерой скорости

Comment: @zRrr, обновил ответ